# Why does my character scroll off the screen instead of staying within the bounds of the screen?

Tags: xna, c#

In my XNA game, I have my "big boss" loaded and in the game screen. I put the code to update its position in the `Update` method of the main class.

The objective is to get the "big boss" to move from the right hand side of the screen to the left. But instead, it moves off the screen and will not move back again.

Here's my code in the `Update` method:

```
public void UpdateBigBoss()
{
  // make the updateBigBoss boss move from r to l
  // and l to r
  // next, take count the collision,
  // by increasing the hit counts by 1
  // when hit counts reach to 10
  // make the big boss alive to false (mean disappear)
  // position of the paddle - start
  motion = Vector2.Zero;

  if (score > 200)
  {
    motion.X = 1;
  }

  motion.X *= BigBossSpeed;
  BigBoss.position += motion;
}
```

Comment: In the future, please post code as code (text) and not as a screenshot. I transcribed your code for you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging your code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void UpdateBigBoss()
{
   motion = Vector2.Zero;

  // make the updateBigBoss boss move from r to l
  // and l to r
  motion.X += dir;
  if(BigBoss.position.X >r || BigBoss.position.X< l){
    var at = BigBoss.position.x
    BigBoss.position.X = Math.max(l,Math.min(r,at));
    dir *= -1;
  }
  // next, take count the collision,
  // by increasing the hit counts by 1
  if(BigBoss.isCollided) hitCount++;

  // when hit counts reach to 10 
  // make the big boss alive to false (mean disappear)
  if(hitCount>=10)BigBoss.alive = false;

  // position of the paddle - start
  //

  if (score > 200)motion.X = 1;

  motion.X *= BigBossSpeed;
  BigBoss.position += motion;
}
```

Comment: Hai,Mr.Tofu, May i ask u what the meaning of dir ? it is direction?

Comment: Yes. :) ...............d

Answer (score 2):

Your code only ever instructs the boss character to move in one direction, forever.

You set the X component of the motion vector to 1 when the score is greater than 200, and then increment the boss's position by that value. You *never* attempt to check if the boss's position after incrementing is within an appropriate threshold of the world boundaries and, if so, set some state to move him the opposite direction.

A simple way to do this would be to check if `bigboss.position.X + bigboss.size.Width >= RightEdgeOfScreen` and if so, set `motion.X` to be -1. Do the same for the opposite edge of the screen.